# Implementar dictionary como interface C#

Tags: c#, interface, dicionário

Estou tentando setar um dictionary em minha interface, porém está dizendo que a classe principal não implementou o dictionary.

Interface.cs

```
public interface IItem
{
    event Action<string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string> ItemToDataGrid;
    void Search();
    int SearchType { get; set; }
    Dictionary<string, string> SearchKey();
}
```

Principal.cs

```
public class Item : IItem
{
    public int _SearchType;
    public int SearchType
    {
        get
        {
            return this._SearchType;
        }
        set
        {
            this._SearchType = value;
        }
    }

    Dictionary<string, string> searchKey = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "Item", "" },            
        { "Character", "" },
    };
```

Estou fazendo algo errado?

Comment: Sim, onde está o `SearchKey()`, o `Search()` e o `ItemToDataGrid`? Sem implementá-los vai dar erro mesmo.

Comment: Colei apenas uma pequena parte do código, o erro está na implementação do dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

A sua classe `Item` tem que esta:

```
oublic class Item : IItem
{
    public int _SearchType;
    public int SearchType
    {
        get
        {
            return this._SearchType;
        }
        set
        {
            this._SearchType = value;
        }
    }
    Dictionary<string, string> searchKey = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
{ "Item", "" },
{ "Character", "" },
};
    public event Action<string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string> ItemToDataGrid;

    public void Search()
    {
        //TODO: Seu código aqui
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> SearchKey()
    {
        //TODO: Seu código aqui

        return searchKey;
    }
}
```

Comment: É que eu colei apenas uma pequena parte do código, o  vs está informando que o erro é na implementação do datagrid.